# Rancher Custom vs Imported Providor API Issue

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

This question is about setting up a Rancher K8s cluster using the Rancher API.

I am having trouble importing the CIS cluster config (in the form of JSON) via the API as doing so flips the provider to "Imported" and prevents the setup of a new cluster because Rancher then thinks the K8s cluster is already setup and you simply need to set up the Rancher management.

However, if I use the JSON that was provided in the Rancher Quickstart the cluster gets set up with the provider set to "Custom" as intended.  This isn't super pressing as I have set up my cluster manually but in case I ever need to rebuild from scratch it would be helpful to have this process automated.

Wanted to ask before I file a GitHub issue, thanks.

Comment: can you add more details? Otherwise, this seems like it should to Rancher support.

Comment: Unfortuanly I can't upload the Cluster config due to the sensitivity of the environment, but what I can say is I am using the Rancher hardening documentation provided at:  
https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/security/hardening-2.3.5/

Best guess is if you pass in a large number of settings, there is logic that being trigger that I'm not seeing.

Comment: Also just to make sure it wasn't my config file, I uploaded the config file from the above link via the api and got the same result.  That being said, if I go into the UI and upload the config,yaml file, the provider does come out as custom (if you use the custom template).

Comment: If you have steps to repro, please file a GH issue.